# AJAX success not displaying my PHP errors or success messages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX call to submit a form and on success I want to display the PHP success message or Error message.

Here is my AJAX success:

```
success: function (data) {
            resultSuccess = $(data).find("#success");
            resultError = $(data).find("#error");        
            $('#resultBlock').html(resultSuccess);
            $('#resultBlock').html(resultError);    
        }
```

If I remove one of them it works. For example if I write it like this:

```
success: function (data) {
            resultSuccess = $(data).find("#success");        
            $('#resultBlock').html(resultSuccess);  
        }
```

I works with no problem its only when I add the other one is when it stops working. How do I write it in a way to show one and/or both messages?

Comment: What does your answer look like? Is it HTML or JSON? Do you have a AJAX Error function setup as well? And could you please define what you see as an 'error': is that an AJAX error (e.g. a timeout or PHP error) or your PHP returning some property defining a semantic error? Have you looked at your Javascript console for errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#resultBlock').html(resultError);
```

This will replace your success message. Why don't you just append it? Assuming your **resultSuccess/resultError** is html code (in fact plain text could be appended as well.. confirmation needed).

```
$('#resultBlock').append(resultSuccess);
$('#resultBlock').append(resultError);
```

You could even do: `$('#resultBlock').append(resultSuccess, resultError);`

Comment: Yes, it is HTMl. I will give i a try now. stand by.